# Rails angular path to image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm trying to reference an image in my `assets/images` folder from a template and having trouble. I feel like I'm missing something very basic but don't think the asset pipeline should be coming into play here. I'm using the [angular templates](https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates) gem. How can I properly reference this image?

```
* app
 * assets
  * images
     prof_pic.jpg
  * javascripts
  * templates
     myHtml.html
```

HTML

```
# I've tried...
<img src="../images/prof_pic.jpg">
<img src="/images/prof_pic.jpg">
<img src="prof_pic.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's to do with Angular you could try using something like `<img ng-src="{{location}}/image-name" />` with $location.path() and then the path to the assets directory.